# How would you evaluate a large scale ontology (the CSO) that comprises of one class and hundreds of individuals?

Tags: ontology, mesh-ontology

Is there such a tool that can automate the evaluation of such a large scale ontology without focusing on the evaluation of the class and mainly focuses on evaluating the ontologies individuals and their semantic relationships?

Comment: What do you mean by evaluate?

Comment: I wish to evaluate the ontology on criteria such as accuracy, completeness, conciseness, consistency, expressiveness, computational efficiency and practical usefulness as a representation of the computer science domain. Basically to evaluate the ontologies overall effectiveness based on set criteria and with the use of an automotive tool

Comment: The primary issue is I am new to ontology and lack the experience to understand how to effectively evaluate the ontology that is large in scale and automatically generated.